# Testing a secure REST endpoint with Spring MVC Test Framework

Tags: spring-mvc, kotlin, spring-test-mvc, spring-security-rest

I am trying to test a secure REST method, using [Spring MVC Test Framework.](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/testing.html#spring-mvc-test-framework)

```
  val result = this.mockMvc!!
     .perform(get("/ping").with(SecurityMockMvcRequestPostProcessors.user("user")))
                .andDo(MockMvcResultHandlers.print())
                .andReturn()

  assertThat(result.response.contentAsString).contains("pong")
```

The problem is that on this request, the mocked server is responding a 302 code, to redirect to a secure channel. The result is never `2xx` code, is always a `302` code. I would like to follow this redirect, or perform the request on secure channel at the first time.

How can I perform this test to do directly on a mocked secure channel?

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I found the solution. I need to call a `secure(true)` on the mocked `get("/")`. It surprised me that this is not on documentation, just on javadocs:

```
  val result = this.mockMvc!!
     .perform(get("/ping").secure(true).with(SecurityMockMvcRequestPostProcessors.user("user")))
                .andDo(MockMvcResultHandlers.print())
                .andReturn()

  assertThat(result.response.contentAsString).contains("pong")
```